# many session endpoints under cookies tab

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, cookies, resources

we have a spring MVC application and I think there is some misconfiguration about session or cookies management basically we have that config about resources, session config and security

XML config:

```
<security:http auto-config=
                           "false" use-expressions="true"
                   disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
                   create-session="ifRequired">
        <security:headers>
            <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        </security:headers>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="sessionFilter" before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll()"/>
        ...
</security:http>
```

Session Filter:

```
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

    private boolean httpOnly=false;
    private boolean secure=false;

    public SessionFilter(boolean httpOnly, boolean secure) {
        this.httpOnly = httpOnly;
        this.secure = secure;
    }

    public SessionFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
            ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        Cookie[] allCookies = req.getCookies();

        if (allCookies != null && !"self-health-check".equals(req.getHeader("User-Agent"))) {
            Cookie session =
                    Arrays.stream(allCookies).filter(x -> x.getName().equals("JSESSIONID"))
                            .findFirst().orElse(null);

            if (session != null) {
                session.setHttpOnly(httpOnly);
                session.setSecure(secure);
                res.addCookie(session);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

And the client is asking this question; why there are a lot of endpoints of sessions?
I don't know it is normal or not.
help, please!

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after some month. The problem is not about my spring MVC config, it is about web.xml config. we needed to add a tracking-mode setting

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```